# How to create a number menu in python

Tags: python, menu

i need a simple python code which makes a number menu, that doesn't take up many lines

```
    print ("Pick an option")
    menu =0
    Menu = input("""
    1. Check Password
    2. Generate Password
    3. Quit
    """)
    if (menu) == 1:
        Password = input("Please enter the password you want to check")
        points =0
```

i tried this but it did not work how i thought it would. i thought this code would work as i have tried it before and it worked but i must have made a mistake in this one.

anyone have any suggestions?

thanks

this is my full code:

```
    print ("Pick an option")
    menu =0
    Menu = input("""
    1. Check Password
    2. Generate Password
    3. Quit
    """)
        if (menu) == 1:
        Password = input("Please enter the password you want to check")
        points =0
        smybols = ['!','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+',]
        querty =                                                                        
      ["qwertyuiop","QWERTYUIOP","asdfghjl","ASDFGHJKL","zxcvbnm","ZXCVBNM"]
if len(password) >24:
    print ('password is too long It must be between 8 and 24 characters')
elif len(password) <8:  
    print ('password is too short It must be between 8 and 24 characters')
elif len(password) >=8 and len(password) <= 24:
    print ('password ok\n')
```

Comment: 1. remove redundant parentheses. 2. `input` returns a string (assuming Python 3). 3. You never set `menu` to anything else than `0` and is not even needed..., so `if Menu == '1':`

Comment: "it did not work how i thought it would" is not a description of your problem

Comment: when i ran that code and proceeded to pick option 1 it did not come back with anything, not even an error

Comment: Nothing is _wrong_ with your block of code. It's just not _right_ and wont execute how you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fundamental flaws with your code that tells us you are not sure what the difference between types are (`str` vs `int`), or what some functions actually do (`input()`). These need to be corrected before you progress any further with your program.

Lets take a look at what your code currently does:

```
print ("Pick an option") # prints a message
menu = 0 # initializes a variable (menu) of type int to 0
Menu = input("""    # prints a message to receive input for variable (Menu) of type str
1. Check Password
2. Generate Password
3. Quit
""") 
if (menu) == 1:  # conditional check against (menu) to int of 1
    ...
```

Now stop here and look a little closer:

`menu = 0` this sets a variable called `menu` equal to `0`; the variable has a lowercase `m` and is of type `int` since you initialized it with an `int`.

`Menu = input(...)` this sets a variable called `Menu` equal to a `str` received from `input()`. So if you input `1`, then what happens is a `str` is returned such that `Menu = '1'`. Notice that the variable has an uppercase `M` unlike `menu` before it; also note the `' '` around the `1`. That means this is a `str`.

`if (menu) == 1:...` this checks the lower case'd `menu` against `1`. Well you initialized `menu = 0` and then you never touch the lower case'd `menu` again, so when you get to this it is still `0`. So of course this will fail.

Given all that, here is what you can do to fix your code:

```
menu = 0
menu = int(input("Pick an option:\n"
                 "1. Check Password\n"
                 "2. Generate Password\n"
                 "3. Quit\n\n"
                 "Option Selected: ")
if (menu) == 1:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing a str and int. convert it into **int**

```
print ("Pick an option")
Menu = int(input("""
1. Check Password
2. Generate Password
3. Quit
"""))
if Menu == 1:
  Password = input("Please enter the password you want to check")
  points =0
```